# Визуализация каталога

Tags: python-3.x, django

Есть загруженная папка с файлами и другими папками. Существует ли возможность ее визуализировать в шаблоне и если да, то как это сделать и с помощью чего?
А, и должна быть возможность выбора элемента каталога(или пути до него).

Comment: Почему нет, первое, что приходит в голову - `python` смотреть окружение (каталог) и рендерить `html`, вроде все просто

Comment: @Igor Sergeevich , а можешь сказать как? на простом примере каком-нибудь...если не сложно...

Comment: Вроде ниже ответили на Ваш вопрос, читайте работа с файловой системой и рендеринг в джанге, я с ней мало работал, готового примера нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть встроенный *FilePathField*

Выглядит не очень красиво в первом приближении, но может сгодиться.

К тому же, Вы можете написать свой widget для более красочного представления.

Пример использования:

forms.py

```
class FileBrowse(forms.Form):
    afile = forms.FilePathField(label='test', path='./mypath', recursive=True)
```

views.py

```
def test_filebrowse(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FileBrowse(request.POST)
        afile = form.data['afile']
        print (afile)
        return HttpResponse(afile)

    else:
        form = FileBrowse()
        context = {'form': form,
               }
        result = render(request, 'site/test.html', context)
    #print (result.content)
        return result
```

test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test file</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/filetest" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: помоги понять, пробую твой код и получаю ошибку FileBrowse' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'. 
программа получает архив, который разархивируется, и мне надо вывести структуру того, что разархивировалось. мне известен путь, куда разархивируется. в твоем коде заменил  form = FileBrowse(request.POST) на form = FileBrowse(path_to_file), где path_to_file - путь до дирректории.и заменил путь до дирректории в самой форме. поправь мои ошибки....

Comment: Попробуйте вот так. Вместо afile = form.cleaned_data['afile'] надо  afile = form.data['afile']. В ответе исправил :)

Comment: теперь дает ошибку ключа=\ говорит нет ключа afile
я ведь правильно понимаю, что в этой строчке form = FileBrowse(request.POST) , мы создаем переменную form , которой присваиваем путь до директории ? или я не верно понял работу?

Comment: @ddsds в данном случае form это объект из form.py. Название ключа то же, что и в afile = forms.FilePathField

Comment: спасибо большое, заработало)
осталось виджет подправить(это я уже сам попробую))